# tensorflow.js: Unable to load a model saved in tfjs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

I am unable to load a sequential model I created using `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` back into node. My model creation looks like this:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node';
      
model = tf.sequential();

// Add a single input layer
model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1.0], units: 1, useBias: true })
);

model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({
      inputShape: [1],
      units: 10,
      activation: 'relu',
      kernelRegularizer: tf.regularizers.l2({ l2: 0.01 }),
      useBias: true
   })
);

// Add additional hidden layers with L2 regularization
model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({
      units: 8,
      activation: 'relu',
      kernelRegularizer: tf.regularizers.l2({ l2: 0.01 }),
      useBias: true
   })
);

model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({
      units: 6,
      activation: 'relu',
      kernelRegularizer: tf.regularizers.l2({ l2: 0.01 }),
      useBias: true
   })
);

// Add an output layer with linear activation
model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, activation: 'linear', useBias: true })
);

// Add an output layer
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true }));
```

I am saving the model like this (bit crude at the moment, but it seems otherwise to work):

```
const createSavableModel = async () => {
   await model.save(tf.io.withSaveHandler(artifacts => {
      modelArtifacts = serialize.serialize(artifacts);
      return Promise.resolve({
         modelArtifactsInfo: {
            dateSaved: new Date()
         } as any
      });
   }));
};
```

and them I'm stashing away the `modelArtifacts` in MongoDB.

Then, when trying to load the model, like this:

```
model = await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(existingModelArtifacts));
```

I get a very long error:

> Error: Unknown layer: {"modelTopology":{"className"...
>
> 1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
> 2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().

Now the model was created entirely in `tensorflow.js`, and the error doesn't really tell me which layer it's unhappy with.

What might be causing this?

## EDIT

I have reduced my model layers:

```
model = tf.sequential();

// Add a single input layer
model.add(
   tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [1.0], units: 1, useBias: true })
);

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, useBias: true }));
```

and here is the topology:

```
{
  "class_name": "Sequential",
  "config": {
    "name": "sequential_1",
    "layers": [
      {
        "class_name": "Dense",
        "config": {
          "units": 1,
          "activation": "linear",
          "use_bias": true,
          "kernel_initializer": {
            "class_name": "VarianceScaling",
            "config": {
              "scale": 1,
              "mode": "fan_avg",
              "distribution": "normal",
              "seed": null
            }
          },
          "bias_initializer": {
            "class_name": "Zeros",
            "config": {}
          },
          "kernel_regularizer": null,
          "bias_regularizer": null,
          "activity_regularizer": null,
          "kernel_constraint": null,
          "bias_constraint": null,
          "name": "dense_Dense1",
          "trainable": true,
          "batch_input_shape": [
            null,
            1
          ],
          "dtype": "float32"
        }
      },
      {
        "class_name": "Dense",
        "config": {
          "units": 1,
          "activation": "linear",
          "use_bias": true,
          "kernel_initializer": {
            "class_name": "VarianceScaling",
            "config": {
              "scale": 1,
              "mode": "fan_avg",
              "distribution": "normal",
              "seed": null
            }
          },
          "bias_initializer": {
            "class_name": "Zeros",
            "config": {}
          },
          "kernel_regularizer": null,
          "bias_regularizer": null,
          "activity_regularizer": null,
          "kernel_constraint": null,
          "bias_constraint": null,
          "name": "dense_Dense2",
          "trainable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "keras_version": "tfjs-layers 4.2.0",
  "backend": "tensor_flow.js"
}
```

So why can't I load this with `tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.fromMemory(existingModelArtifacts))`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I decided to go via the filesystem:

```
const createArchive = async (sourceDir: string): Promise<Buffer> => {
   const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });
   const chunks: Buffer[] = [];

   return new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
      archive.on('data', (data) => {
         chunks.push(data);
      });

      archive.on('end', () => {
         resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
      });

      archive.directory(sourceDir, false);
      archive.finalize();
   });
};

const extractBuffer = (buffer: Buffer, destinationDir: string): Promise<void> => {
   return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      const extractor = unzipper.Extract({ path: destinationDir });

      extractor.on('error', (err) => {
         reject(`Error extracting archive: ${err.message}`);
      });

      extractor.on('close', () => {
         console.log(`Archive extracted to: ${destinationDir}`);
         resolve();
      });

      extractor.write(buffer);
      extractor.end();
   });
};

const modelToBuffer = async (model: any) => {
   const modelSaveTempDir = await mkdtemp(path.join(os.tmpdir(), `tf-${pairName}`));
   await model.save(`file://${modelSaveTempDir}`);

   return createArchive(modelSaveTempDir);
};

const bufferToModel = async (buffer: Buffer): Promise<any> => {
   const modelTempDir = await mkdtemp(path.join(os.tmpdir(), `tf-${pairName}`));
   await extractBuffer(buffer, modelTempDir);
   return await tf.loadLayersModel(`file://${modelTempDir}/model.json`);
};
```